# Model-free ultra-local function approximation

Tags: calculus, integration, control-theory, inverse-laplace

I've been reading a lot about model-free control and I came across the concept of the ultra-local model. There is a really intricate approach outlined [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236965966_Model-free_control) but I'm having an issue with one part outlined below.

[Image of the equations I have the question about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFxEM.png)

I'm not sure how the authors went from $y+s\frac{dy}{ds} = -\frac{\phi}{s^2} + \alpha\frac{du}{ds}$ to the next equation for $\phi$. It is mentioned in the article that it has to do with $\int_{\tau_{i}}^{\tau_{f}} F(\tau)d\tau$ and said in a conference that it is the averaging integral, but I don't see how. The equations are outlined in section 3.4.1 in the article.

Comment: This paper is an absolute nightmare to read. It is full of typos, inconsistent notations, and unclear statements. I am happy to help but I will need some time.

Comment: Not a problem, thank you so much. If you have an IEEE account the following article uses with same strategy with significantly more detail, although the jump from (7) to (8) still escapes me [link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9779978). It seems as though the authors are using the fact that multiplication in the laplace domain is convolution in the time domain.

Comment: Multiplication by $s$ in the Laplace domain corresponds to derivation in the time-domain and vice-versa. Multiplication of functions in the Laplace domain corresponds to the convolution of their inverse Laplace transforms and vice-versa.

Comment: That makes sense to me, thank you. I guess the two parts I'm unclear on is why they're multiplying both sides of (5) by 1/s^2*d/ds (I know that the d/ds is to get rid of the initial conditions but why that specific value) and the bounds of the integral. Any ideas for that? And thank you so much for your help btw!

Comment: In my opinion, it should not be said that both sides are multiplied by $d/ds$ but rather than both sides are differentiated with respect to $s$. Since the initial condition is a constant (i.e. independent of $s$), then it goes away after differentiation. The division by $s$ is to make the expression involving only time-integration and to also filter out potential noise on the measurement $y$. The bounds of the integral is because you consider an ultra local model over a small horizon $T$. I am still figuring out the integrand.

Comment: This makes sense. I agree that I should rather have said "differentiated with respect to s". I appreciate the help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am considering the notation of the paper [enter link description here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9779978) which you mention in one the comments.

First, note that we have the following equality

$$\int_0^T\int_0^sz(\theta)d\theta ds=\int_0^T(T-s)z(s)ds,$$

which can be proven by integrating by parts.

The starting point is the following expression in the frequency domain

$$-\dfrac{\phi}{s^4}=\dfrac{1}{s^2}Y(s)+\dfrac{1}{s}\dfrac{d}{ds}Y(s)-\dfrac{\alpha}{s^2}\dfrac{d}{ds}U(s).$$

Let us consider first the terms in $Y(s)$ and convert them to the time-domain using the inverse Laplace transform. We have that

$$\dfrac{1}{s^2}Y(s)\rightarrow \int_0^T\int_0^\tau y(\theta)d\theta d\tau=\int_0^T(T-\tau)y(\tau)d\tau$$
and
$$\dfrac{1}{s}\dfrac{d}{ds}Y(s)\rightarrow -\int_0^T\tau y(\tau)d\tau.$$

If we sum the two, get the term

$$\int_0^T(T-2\tau)y(\tau)d\tau.$$

Similarly, the term in $U(s)$ becomes

$$\dfrac{\alpha}{s^2}\dfrac{d}{ds}U(s)\rightarrow -\alpha\int_0^T(T-\tau)\tau u(\tau)d\tau.$$

Therefore, the time-domain expression of the right-hand side is given by

$$\int_0^T\left[(T-2\tau)y(\tau)+\alpha(T-\tau)\tau u(\tau)\right]d\tau.$$

Now we need to consider the term in $\phi/s^4$ and we have that

$$\dfrac{1}{s^4}\rightarrow \dfrac{T^3}{3!}=\dfrac{T^3}{6}$$

which finally yields

$$-\dfrac{T^3}{6}\phi=\int_0^T\left[(T-2\tau)y(\tau)+\alpha(T-\tau)\tau u(\tau)\right]d\tau$$
or, equivalently,

$$\phi=-\dfrac{6}{T^3}\int_0^T\left[(T-2\tau)y(\tau)+\alpha(T-\tau)\tau u(\tau)\right]d\tau.$$

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much.